# How to create git hooks in Windows with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, git, githooks

I have been following [this](https://medium.com/@Sergeon/using-javascript-in-your-git-hooks-f0ce09477334) guide on how to use Node.js to script git hooks. However, the guide is using a Unix based system whilst I am running on a Windows machine.

I have also found [this](https://www.tygertec.com/git-hooks-practical-uses-windows/) guide on running git hooks on a Windows machine, but it is not using Node.js

- I am running a [pre-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script in my package.json file to set a custom git hooks location.
- I am using VSCode as my editor and would like the git hooks to run when I use the UI for commits etc. However I am using command line initially to try and get the hooks to fire.

**package.json excerpt**

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "git config core.hooksPath ./git.hooks"
  },
```

In my `git.hooks` folder I have a `pre-commit.js` file.

I have updated the first line to reflect the fact I'd like to execute the script running Node.js

**pre-commit.js**

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/nodejs/node.exe

console.log('Hello world!');

process.exit(1);
```

If I run this script directly I get a Microsoft JScript compilation error - Invalid character on line 1 char 1.

If I do a commit, I get no errors but nothing happens.

Can anyone guide me through the process of creating a Node.js hook in Windows. I would rather create one myself than use a package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Name the hook exactly `pre-commit`, without `.js`.
2. Change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/env node`. But make sure that `C:/Program\ Files/nodejs/node.exe` has been added to the environment variable `PATH`.
3. Place it in `<repo>/.git/hooks`.
4. Make it executable. In git-bash, run `chmod a+x <repo>/.git/hooks/pre-commit`.

Now it should work as expected.

Comment: This works, even in Powershell. I'm not sure I understand why though? How does Powershell interpret that first line?

Comment: @Antfish It's not entirely clear to me. I think it's interpreted in git bash environment in the end, so it doesn't matter if you are running `git commit` in cmd, powershell, git bash or gui tools.